# int object is not an iterable python problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, integer

So I keep getting a

```
  File "main.py", line 77, in <module>
    dealer_cards_total = sum(dealer_cards)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I've tried various 'solutions' and tried analyzing other programs that have the same error as mine but I can't seem to find anything,I marked where the error is coming from according to the **program** using a long line of hashtags, here's the code:

```
import random
import time



Ace = 11
Jack = 10
Queen = 10
King = 10


cards = [Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King]


e = 0
Ace_21 = False
player_bal = 0
dealer_bal = 0
player_cards = []
dealer_cards = []
player_cards_total = 0
dealer_cards_total = 0
card = ''
move = ''
moves = 0

def get_card():
  return(int(cards[random.randrange(1, 13)]))


dealer_cards =  [get_card()]
player_cards = [get_card(), get_card()]
player_cards_total = sum(player_cards)


def get_move():
  
  if moves == 0:
    print('\nDealer\'s cards: ', dealer_cards)
    print('Your cards: ', player_cards,'\nTotal: ', player_cards_total)
  move = input('Chose your next move: ')
  if move in ['h', 'Hit']:
    move = 'hit'
  elif move in ['s', 'Stand']:
    move = 'stand'
  return(move)



while player_cards_total < 21:
  player_cards_total = sum(player_cards)
  dealer_cards_total = sum(dealer_cards)
  if player_cards_total > 20:
    print('\n\n//////////////////////////\nDealer\'s cards: ', dealer_cards)
    print('Your cards: ', player_cards,'\nTotal: ', player_cards_total, '\n//////////////////////////')
    print('\nBUST\n')
    break
  move = get_move()
  
  if move == 'hit':
    player_cards.append(get_card())
  else:
    break

######################################### lines:
if player_cards_total > 21:                66
   print('You lose!!!')                    67
elif player_cards_total == 21:             68
  print('Great job, you win')              69
else:                                      70
  print('DEALER\'S TURN')                  71
  while dealer_cards_total < 20:           72
    if e == 0:                             73
      dealer_cards.append(get_card())      74
      e = 1                                75
    print(dealer_cards)                    76
    dealer_cards_total = sum(dealer_cards) 77
    dealer_cards = get_card()              78
#####################################################
if dealer_cards_total == 21:
  print('YOU LOSE')
elif dealer_cards_total > 21:
  print('DEALER BUSTED\nYOU WIN!!!')
elif dealer_cards_total > player_cards_total and dealer_cards_total < 22:
  print('YOU LOSE')
else:
  print('YOU WIN')
```

It's probably an easy fix but I'm kind of a begginer and I haven't gotten this problem before

Comment: In line 78 you do `dealer_cards = get_card()` and then in the next iteration `dealer_cards` is a number rather than a list. Looks like this might be the problem. You should probably change that to `dealer_cards = [get_card()]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I accidentally put ```dealer_cards = get_card()``` instead of ```dealer_cards.append(get_card())```. Fixed it now, works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs in these lines:

```
dealer_cards_total = sum(dealer_cards) 
dealer_cards = get_card()
```

The reason for this is that sum() expects a list.

However, get_card() returns an integer. As such, after the first iteration, dealer_cards changes from a list to an integer.

It seems like you accounted for this at the beginning of the script:

```
dealer_cards =  [get_card()]
```

Without evaluating the rest of your script, it seems at least the solution should lie somewhere with making sure that dealer_cards remains a list.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I accidentally put ```dealer_cards = get_card()``` instead of ```dealer_cards.append(get_card())``` at line 78. Fixed it now, works perfectly